# Can PayPal IPN Notification POST be faked?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an ipn file for paypal where paypal send me an notification whenever an transaction is made, once the transcation is made and paypal send me notification to my php file, i start processing that transaction.

User pay -> Paypal send notificaiton with POST values of transcation to my php file -> Transaction is being proccesed

My question is , can this POST values be sent from elsewhere insted of real Paypal? like someone will send fake post values into my ipn php file and my script will think is paypal and will start processing fake transactions.

Answer (score 2):

If you verify your IPN calls, then no, they can't be faked.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the Paypal IPN message could be faked, but the notification process includes a verification step that allows you to verify the IPN message.

This is the process, taken from the [Paypal developer page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#example_req_resp):

The IPN message authentication protocol consists of four steps:

1. PayPal HTTP POSTs your listener an IPN message that notifies you of an event.
2. Your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal.
3. Your listener HTTP POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal; the message must contain the same fields (in the same order) as the original message and be encoded in the same way as the original message.
4. PayPal sends a single word back - either VERIFIED (if the message matches the original) or INVALID (if the message does not match the original).

Comment: Exactly. And it's step #3 and #4 that ensure the IPN message you're verifying is a genuine IPN message which originated from PayPal. Of course, you'll need to run your own checks on things like the receiver_email so that it matches your account.